# Google protocol buffer messag to byte array C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, protocol-buffers

I'm currently using two message protocols, one is google proto and the other is c-structs. What is the best solution to convert a google protocol buffer message (`MessageLite`) to a byte array?

I want, for example, to convert the following google proto message:

```
message GoogleRequest
{
     optional int32 request = 1 [default = 0];
}
```

to:

```
struct Request
{
    int request;
};
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
GoogleRequest reqMsg;
reqMsg.set_request(1234);

int size = reqMsg.ByteSize();
Request* reqStruct = new Request;
reqMsg.SerializeToArray((void*)reqStruct , size);
```

Any suggestions, or is the best way just to do:

```
reqStruct->request = reqMsg.request();
```

I have a lot of message types and I would be awesome to find a generic way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You say you want to convert your message to a byte array, but your code suggests you're trying to convert it to a C struct (`Request`). Converting to a C struct is not supported. Converting to a byte array (that is, an array of `char`) is easy:

```
int size = reqMsg.ByteSize();
char* array = new char[size];
reqMsg.SerializeToArray(array, size);
```

Or, another way:

```
std::string bytes = reqMsg.SerializeAsString();
const char* array = bytes.data();
int size = bytes.size();
```

However, this array is not a struct, and it could have many different sizes depending on the content. There is no way to convert to a struct except to write code which copies over each field manually.

Comment: In 2021, ByteSize has been replaced by ByteSizeLong:

    warning: ‘int google::protobuf::MessageLite::ByteSize() const’ is deprecated: Please use ByteSizeLong() instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

Simply change your code to:
    long size = reqMsg.ByteSizeLong()